# AmCharts.makeChart is not working but AmCharts.AmSerialChart works

Tags: amcharts

I am trying to create a column chart using AmCharts library...
It is working fin when I user the old method

```
            var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.theme = 'light';
            chart.autoMarginOffset = 20;
            chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS";...
```

But it is not working when i use the efficient method:

```
var newChart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv1", option);
```

The target div itself not modified. It seems the 
`AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv1", option)` not even affecting anything.
no error in console.

Please help me to find out the reason.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle please?

Comment: I couldn't recreate the problem.. It is happening only in my application (trying to create a custom visualization in a kibana Plugin).. [link](https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/06/writing-kibana-4-plugins-visualizations-using-data/) ...

Comment: I can't help you then, I'm sorry. The only thing I can tell you to do is to check for typos in your configuration, else the problem shouldn't be amCharts. The "efficient" method is just to simplify and uses the "old" method internal to create the chart.

Comment: The `makeChart` method was introduced in Version 3 of the library. Are you using V3 or still on V2?